# Passing generic types as generic method parameters in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

First let me apologize for the terrible title, but I had no idea how to summarize this in a single sentence.

```
public class GenericFun {
    public class TypedStream<I extends OutputStream> {
        I input;

        public I getInput() { return input; }
        public void setInput(I input) { this.input = input; }
    }

    public abstract class GarbageWriter<I extends OutputStream> {
        public void writeGarbage(I output) throws Exception {
            output.write("Garbage".getBytes());
        }
    }

    public class GarbageWriterExecutor<I extends OutputStream> extends GarbageWriter<I> {
        public void writeTrash(TypedStream stream) throws Exception{
            this.writeGarbage(stream.getInput());       // Error
            this.writeGarbage((I)stream.getInput());    // OK
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code (the OutputStream is just an example) in class `GarbageWriterExecutor` class in the method first line causes compilation error, while the second one don't. I have two questions regarding this.

1. Why `stream.getInput()` causes error, even though `TypedStream.I` is known to extend `OutputStream`?
2. How can I solve this issue without the ugly casting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TypedStream stream` will disable generic type checking and thus the compiler only knows that `getInput()` will return an object, hence the error.

Try `writeTrash(TypedStream<I> stream)` instead.

Maybe you event want to use `writeTrash(TypedStream<? extends I> stream)` in order to be able to pass any `TypedStream` which is parameterized for `I` or subclasses of `I`.

Yet another alternative would be

```
public class GarbageWriterExecutor extends GarbageWriter<OutputStream> {
  public void writeTrash(TypedStream<?> stream) throws Exception{
    this.writeGarbage(stream.getInput());     
  }
}
```

or

```
public class GarbageWriterExecutor extends GarbageWriter<OutputStream> {
  public void writeTrash(TypedStream<? extends OutputStream> stream) throws Exception{
    this.writeGarbage(stream.getInput());     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because your method

```
public void writeTrash(TypedStream stream)
```

should also make sure `TypedStream` type is defined, like this :

```
 public void writeTrash(TypedStream<I> stream)
```

Edit : Thomas answer actually explain why

> TypedStream stream will disable generic type checking and thus the compiler only knows that getInput() will return an object, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
public class GarbageWriterExecutor<I extends OutputStream> extends GarbageWriter<I> {
    public void writeTrash(TypedStream<I> stream) throws Exception {
        this.writeGarbage(stream.getInput());
    }
}
```

I.e. parameterize your `TypedStream` parameter with `I`.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Resolve this by using this code.

 public void writeTrash(TypedStream<I> stream) throws Exception{
            this.writeGarbage(stream.getInput());       
            this.writeGarbage(stream.getInput());   
        }
2.  In Generic class class name is followed by a type parameter section. If you are not    doing this then you have to do casting.
```